# Transaction Not Showing up, all others Queued..Please help

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet

The following transaction is not showing up and when I send a 0eth to myself that gets queued:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x58dd1572721eee70a796dd021b19cd08dbde7f5e5be90caa9c2ae9fe0151a0d9

Please refer to the screenshot of metamask,as you can see there are total 10 pending in queue.How do I fix this? Please help

[image: MetaMask Queued]

**Update**: I checked the nonce of the new transactions, even though I put 481 in there which is of the original tran. but the new is getting incremented, it was 490. Can someone please help me here?

[image]

Comment: your metamask says "Not connected", please fix that

Comment: Hi, sorry please check this now.It says connected but still same issue.Please check my previous Update too.

Comment: why are you using "send offline"

Comment: I came across articles saying if I send offline with the nonce same as previous transaction and with 0 eth then it will replace the current one. But the problem is even this new transaction gets queued and the original is still not found. Also, one reason is the new tran is being generated with a new nonce even though I put 481 it got created with 490.